# Nodata value error when uploading .tif files into Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, metadata, nodata

I am working with some data that somebody else prepared. The data consists of DEM .tif files that have been remapped to different values. When I attempt to upload these files to Google Earth Engine via the assets tab, I get the following error:

> Error: No data value -128.0 cannot be applied to band #0 of type
> Short <0, 255>.

Is there any way i can alter the data in QGIS to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

If the Earth Engine error is correct, the nodata value is incompatible with the data type of your image because -128 cannot be represented in an unsigned integer. You can fix that in QGIS by re-exporting the image with a compatible data type using the `Raster > Conversion > Translate (Convert Format)` tool.

If the `int8` data type isn't supported by your QGIS version (it was added recently), you could either:

1. Continue using `-128` as the nodata value but use an `int16` data type. This will make a larger file, but allow you to keep using the same nodata value.
2. Assign a new nodata value (like `0` or `255`) and use a `byte` data type. Just make sure that the nodata value you choose isn't being used for valid data.

Both of those can be done using the `Translate` tool.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! That worked!